# Unable to connect to 5GHz WiFi on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, macos, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I'm trying to connect my machine to a 5GHz WiFi but I can't seem to do this on Ubuntu. I have a dual boot system on my machine, with OSX as the other OS, and on that, I'm able to connect and use on 5GHz.

```
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=1496 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

enxc6d291c8c5d3  no wireless extensions.
```

I'm currently tethering on USB from my phone right now.

```
$ iwlist wlp3s0 freq
wlp3s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
```

I'm certain my machine can run on 5GHz networks, but I can't detect the 5GHz network. Can someone please help?

Comment: I have exactly that problem (I'm dual boot with windows, any luck?)

Answer (score -1):

The only difference that could cause this is a poorly implemented / misconfigured driver.

You havent included the make/model so I cant link you to any resources but chances are Ubuntu has pulled a generic and you'll need to manually install the most appropriate one instead.

Comment: I'm using a Broadcom chip [14e4:43ba] (rev 01)
`03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 01)`